# TypeError | Cannot read property 'DisplayName' of undefined

Tags: javascript

Need to set Value of Id as environment variable from API response I tried this but getting error
`'TypeError | Cannot read property 'DisplayName' of undefined'`

I wrote the code and i am able to get the id for the `DisplayName=Samsung XCover 4` but unable to set the Id as environment variable.

```
eval(globals.bigint_fix);    
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

for (var i=0; i<=jsonData.Offerings.length; i++)
{
    if(jsonData.Offerings[i].DisplayName === "Samsung XCover 4")
    {
        pm.environment.set("offering", jsonData.Offerings[i].DisplayName.Id);
    }
}
```

Error:

> TypeError | Cannot read property 'DisplayName' of undefined

API Response:

```
{
    "Offerings": [{
        "Amount": 28592,
        "CurrencyCode": "USD",
        "DisplayName": "Samsung XCover 4",
        "Id": 1910256761716000500,
        "Language": "en-CA",
        "LineOfBusinesses": [
            10048
        ],
        "MarketingViews": [],
        "Name": "Samsung XCover 4",
        "OfferType": 1,
        "ShortDescription": "Offering bundle includes:\n- Airtime"
    }]
}
```

Comment: Try changing `i<=jsonData.Offerings.length` on line 3 to `i<jsonData.Offerings.length`.

Comment: replace `jsonData.Offerings[i].DisplayName.Id` with `jsonData.Offerings[i].Id`

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues. First the change `i<=jsonData.Offerings.length` to `i<jsonData.Offerings.length`. Secondly this line `jsonData.Offerings[i].DisplayName.Id` will throw another error since value of `DisplayName` is a string and there is no key by name `id` in it.

Replace that by `jsonData.Offerings[i].Id`

```js
let jsonData = {
  "Offerings": [{
    "Amount": 28592,
    "CurrencyCode": "USD",
    "DisplayName": "Samsung XCover 4",
    "Id": 1910256761716000500,
    "Language": "en-CA",
    "LineOfBusinesses": [
      10048
    ],
    "MarketingViews": [],
    "Name": "Samsung XCover 4",
    "OfferType": 1,
    "ShortDescription": "Offering bundle includes:\n- Airtime"
  }]
}



for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.Offerings.length; i++) {
  if (jsonData.Offerings[i].DisplayName === "Samsung XCover 4") {
    console.log(jsonData.Offerings[i].Id);
  }
}
```